# bootstrap menu customization

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu, navigation, customization

I am using Bootstrap 2.2.2 and I was curious if anyone has implemented or has the knowledge on how to customize the mobile navigation? Currently bootstrap, when in a mobile or tablet view, displays a button which you can press to drop the menu down vertically.

What I want is to be able to have the menu pull from the right hand side or horizontal. It would be ideal to have a menu that is similar to the Facebook App or Google+ App, where when you hit the menu button the menu slides out from the left hand side pushing all the content of the page to the right.

Can anyone guide me on how to do this with  bootstrap? Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace the dropdown menu or do you want to keep that dropdown meny as well as another show and hide menu as well. Can you show a sample page somewhere or a tinkerbin or jsfiddle to look at what you are after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently in Bootstrap there is no such component. To sum up my search for slide menus, you have three options:
a) override bootstrap css file: here you have a code example:http://codepen.io/michaelschofield/pen/FAnKG
b) angularjs module and slide out menu for your application:http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-mobile-menu
c) jquery plugins just search the web with query+slide menu

Comment: Thank you so much for the direction to these examples. These are both great! Ultimately I found a solution in the meantime and have implemented it: http://jakiestfu.github.io/Snap.js/demo/apps/default.html